# Why ng-Model is not updated in HTML input element when I set element.value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs-ng-model

For example I have HTML input field:

```
<input id="firstName" ng-model="applicant.firstName" type="text">
<button ng-click="updateFirstName()">Update</button>
<h4>See content of ngModel: {{applicant.firstName}}</h4>
```

then in AngularJS Controller I have method that uses pure JavaScript to get element by Id and update its value:

```
  $scope.updateFirstName = function() {
      var element = document.getElementById("firstName");
      element.value = 'Updated!';
  };
```

So when I click Update button, input element value gets successfully updated, but ng-model is not. It suppose to create $scope.applicant.firstName and assign value to it, but it does not happen. 
It gets updated only when I type something in HTML input text box.

How can I make ng-model to get updated when I change is from JS code through element? May there is a way to trigger something when HTML input value is changed?

I know if I use pure AngularJS, I can just inside Controller call:

```
$scope.applicant = {};
$scope.applicant.firstName = "Updated!";
```

and it will update both with no problems, but in the specifics of this task, I have to use JS element and update its value.

Comment: First you shouldn't access DOM element from a controller. Second as you're using Vanilla JS to update the value Angular doesn't know about it and using `element.value` actually update the `property` of the element and not the `attribute` so anything watching attribute changes would not run.

Answer (score 0):

If `$scope.applicant.firstName` doesn't already exist, ng-model will not create it for you.

You use ng-model to bind an existing variable to an HTML element.

Note the example from than [Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) declares $scope.val in the controller.

```
<script>
 angular.module('inputExample', [])
   .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
     $scope.val = '1';
   }]);
</script>
<style>
  .my-input {
    transition:all linear 0.5s;
    background: transparent;
  }
  .my-input.ng-invalid {
    color:white;
    background: red;
  }
</style>
<p id="inputDescription">
 Update input to see transitions when valid/invalid.
 Integer is a valid value.
</p>
<form name="testForm" ng-controller="ExampleController">
  <input ng-model="val" ng-pattern="/^\d+$/" name="anim" class="my-input"
         aria-describedby="inputDescription" />
</form>
```